CleverTap is null
I'm implementing cleverTap in kotlin android but after pushing notification I got message in Logcat:

[PushType:FCM] Found Valid Notification Message
[PushType:FCM] received notification from CleverTap: "Bunde data"
[PushType:FCM]  not renderning since cleverTapAPI is null.

In application file before super.onCreate() i have this:
CleverTapAPI.setDebugLevel(CleverTapAPI.LogLevel.VERBOSE)
CleverTapAPI.setNotificationHandler(PushTemplateNotificationHandler() as NotificationHandler)
ActivityLifecycleCallback.register(this)

and Manifest:
<service
    android:name="com.clevertap.android.sdk.pushnotification.fcm.FcmMessageListenerService"
    android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
     </intent-filter>
</service>

